# MFC C++ Background Thread

Tags: c++, mfc, background-thread

I am making an MFC (document/view) application and I want it to constantly listen in the background for when a device is connected and then automatically copy the files on the device without the user needing to interact or pause/disturb what they are doing.

Is creating a worker thread the same as having a background thread?  Would I create it as a function in the document file or as a separate class?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they behave as a normal background threads, you have a function that gets parameter, and then you can enter your listener loop. I would put this function in separate class, maybe in a form of a singleton class, this way you can easily start/stop your device listener. If you would ever need to send information of progress from this worker thread to GUI, use PostMessage to you GUI windows.

as always MSDN provides tons of documentation:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975t8ks0%28v=vs.80%29