# c++ mfc how to continue to use application while action is running

Tags: c++, button, mfc

can anyone help me figure out how would I go about being able to continue to use my program while an action is in progress without having to wait until it has finished? when I click the start button I created, I can't use the program or even move the window of the program until the action the button press does has finished.

thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is a background thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150596/mfc-c-background-thread

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975t8ks0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: thank you very much, that is a big help.